# Faust Python Blocking Function

Tags: python-3.x, faust

I'm looking a good way to run a none async lib inside a faust agent :

```
@app.agent(topic)
async def cp_agent(cp_stream):
    async for batch in cp_stream.take(100, within=5):
        print("------ Indexing a CPE  BATCH -----")
        [... Here Use of A NONE Async Function like elastic-dsl]
```

I read the post   [Adding Faust to your Existing Architecture](https://robinhood.engineering/adding-faust-to-your-existing-architecture-39b0ebd1f7c9)
I deduce we need to use only IO/Async library inside faust.
There is now way to make a none async lib into faust ?
I saw some monkey patching with : (gevent and eventlet) but seems to not working

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: no, you can't use blocking libraries inside `faust`. Use [async/await  support](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/async.html) in the official python library or usesome thing like [aioelasticsearch](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioelasticsearch).

**Logn answer**: yes, you can, it is quite easy to start, but

Dig in this [How to use asyncio with existing blocking library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063331/how-to-use-asyncio-with-existing-blocking-library) to find a solution.
But read carefully first answer to this [asyncio, wrapping a normal function as asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57336602/asyncio-wrapping-a-normal-function-as-asynchronous).

Please, think twice before start a long answer solution.