# Asyncio is blocking using FastAPI

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

I have a function that make a post request with a lot of treatment. All of that takes 30 seconds.

I need to execute this function every 6 mins. So I used asyncio for that ... But it's not asynchrone my api is blocked since the end of function ... Later I will have treatment that takes 5 minutes to execute.

```
def update_all():
    # do request and treatment (30 secs)

async run_update_all():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(6 * 60)
        update_all()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(run_update_all())
```

So, I don't understand why during the execute time of update_all() all requests comming are in pending, waiting for the end of update_all() instead of being asynchronous

Comment: If `update_all()` is not an async function it will block the thread. It's not clear why you are expecting it not to.

Comment: Because I think there is a way to use a blocking function in a thread ? But I don't know how to do that

Comment: You may be looking for the [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) method, which will wrap a synchronous function in a thread (or process) so that it doesn't block your event loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asyncio, wrapping a normal function as asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57336602/asyncio-wrapping-a-normal-function-as-asynchronous)

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer with the indication of larsks

I did that :

```
def update_all():
    # Do synchrone post request and treatment that take long time

async def launch_async():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(120)
        loop.run_in_executore(None, update_all)

asyncio.create_task(launch_async())
```

With that code I'm able to launch a synchrone function every X seconds without blocking the main thread of FastApi :D

I hope that will help other people in the same case than me.

Comment: Thanks this helped me get around the blocking behavior I was stuck on trying to get an "after startup" event to fire (basically launch this async task in startup event function with a timer)